# How can I add items in the node editor context menu in 2.8?

Tags: python, operator

How can I add my operator to existing right-click (context menu) in the shader editor?
[image]

Comment: It is not generic right-click menu, in the 2.79 it is called "specials" menu. Now in 2.8 it moved to right-click instead of "w" button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Shader Editor* context menu is called `NODE_MT_context_menu` (found by inspecting *Preferences> Keymap> Node Editor* and looking for *Right Mouse*) and we can '`append`' (add) a draw function, which draws your menu item, into the existing menu. In the example below I have used the *Node Editor*'s existing 'Duplicate' operator.

```
def draw_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.separator()
    layout.operator("node.duplicate_move", text="My new context menu item")

def register():
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.append(draw_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.remove(draw_menu)
```

Explanation:

- The `draw_menu` function deals with the UI that you want to add to the context menu (an `operator`) by using the `bl_idname` of your operator - in this case `node.duplicate_move`.
- The `register` function should contain, in addition to the code that registers your operator, the code to `append` that UI into the existing menu.
- In the case of an add-on, the `unregister` function will remove the UI you added.

**Note:**

- The `separator()` line is not required, but useful for keeping your UI separate from the existing one.
- `prepend` can be used instead of `append` to add items to the top of the menu instead of the bottom.

Some more information about menus can be found in the [2.80 Python API documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html). A few examples of extending the existing UI can be found in the Python templates included with Blender via the *Templates* menu in the *Text Editor* header.

Answer (score 3):

Ray's [excellent answer and explanation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150106/90622) still hold true for Blender `3.x` and current the API. These also helped me with adding menu items:

- Searching `Keymap` for "context menu" gives what's available across for all editors.
  [image]
- Enabling `Developer Extras` and `Python Tooltips` in `Preferences` ... `Interface` ... `Display` gives info on hover in context of the editor / workspace you're in currently.
  [image]

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who came here looking for the context menu for mesh editing mode, the keyword is `VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu`

so the code would be

```
def register():
     bpy.types.NODE_MT_context_menu.append(draw_menu)
```

Which is the menu that appears when you right-click (by default) in *Edit Mode*. For some reason, I couldn't find it in the Blender API reference.

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/MZ93/?sorting=hot

https://blenderartists.org/t/context-sensitive-menu-in-blender/515689/5